# Web publish to azure connection strings _databasepublish

Tags: asp.net, azure, publish

When publishing my site to azure, an additional connection string is being added with the original name appended with _datapublish.

How can I stop this from happening? I'm happy to manage my connection strings using web.config transforms.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyAppContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:sdfdfsfsdf.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyApp;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="StorageConnectionString" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=MyApp;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add name="MyAppContext_DatabasePublish" connectionString="MyAppContext_DatabasePublish.ConnetionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I now get the following error on the live site:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

When comparing the released file I notice that this is also added under the entityFramework section:

```
<contexts>
  <context type="MyApp.Data.MyAppContext, MyApp.Data">
    <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[MyApp.Data.MyAppContext, MyApp.Data], [MyApp.Data.Migrations.Configuration, MyApp.Data]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="MyAppContext_DatabasePublish" />
      </parameters>
    </databaseInitializer>
  </context>
</contexts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here...

[Publish ASP.NET MVC 5 website to Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618002/publish-asp-net-mvc-5-website-to-windows-azure)

The datapublish stuff is still in the web.config but no exception is thrown when I run the app anymore. At least there is no more need to edit the file every time after deploying.

Answer (score 1):

This second connection string is automatically injected if the "Apply Code First migrations" (VS 2012) or "Execute Code First Migrations" (VS 2013) checkbox is checked in the deployment wizard:

[image]

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438730/94853) for more details